# Clarity Wizard - Add a css-selector to a custom wizard button

Tags: css, vmware-clarity, clarity

I have a wizard with the following custom wizard buttons:

```
<clr-wizard-button [type]="'cancel'">Cancel</clr-wizard-button> 
<clr-wizard-button [type]="'previous'">Previous</clr-wizard-button>
<clr-wizard-button [type]="'next'">Next</clr-wizard-button>
<clr-wizard-button [type]="'custom-save'">Save</clr-wizard-button>
```

Now I want to style the button of type `custom-save` with a custom color and for this, I need to apply a css-selector. `attr.class` won't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

edit:
Formatted html output of the custom-save button:

```
<clr-wizard-button class="clr-wizard-btn-wrapper" _nghost-c5="" ng-reflect-type="custom-save" ng-reflect-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false">
  <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn clr-wizard-btn" type="button">
  Speichern
  </button>
</clr-wizard-button>
```

Comment: What is the **output** HTML?

Comment: <clr-wizard-button class="clr-wizard-btn-wrapper" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-type="save" ng-reflect-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false">
        <button _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn clr-wizard-btn" type="button">
            Speichern
        </button>
    </clr-wizard-button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place a custom class on your ClrWizardButton and it will be rendered for you.

```
<clr-wizard-button [type]="'custom'" class="my-custom-button">Cancel</clr-wizard-button>
```

This will render out as you see, where you can target the button using `.my-custom-button button` in your CSS.

```
<clr-wizard-button class="my-custom-button clr-wizard-btn-wrapper ng-star-inserted" _nghost-c1="" ng-reflect-type="custom-previous" aria-hidden="false">
  <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn clr-wizard-btn btn-outline clr-wizard-btn--secondary" type="button">Custom</button>
</clr-wizard-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this renders a standard `button` with a `type`, then an *attribute* selector would work.

```css
button[type="custom-save"] {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button type="custom-save">Save</button>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the `type="button"` on a custom button.